# Installing tshark on RHEL

Tags: linux, wireshark, yum, rhel, tshark

Is there a way to install tshark on RHEL machines using yum install?

when i did: `yum install tshark`

I got back:

```
Setting up Install Process
No package tshark available.
Nothing to do
```

When i did: yum list *tshark*
I got back:

```
 Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
Error: No matching Packages to list
```

Comment: Are you certain `tshark` is available via the RHEL repositories?

Comment: Thats what im not sure of. Is there an alternate way of installing it?

Comment: need to be at http://superuser.com

Comment: Today (14 May 2018) I installed Wireshark on RHEL Server 6.5 (Santiago) by running following:    1. rpm -ivh libsmi-0.4.8-4.el6.x86_64.rpm    2. rpm -ivh wireshark-1.8.10-25.el6.x86_64.rpm    3. rpm -ivh --replacefiles glib2-2.28.8-9.el6.x86_64.rpm    4. rpm -ivh --replacefiles gtk2-2.24.23-9.el6.x86_64.rpm    5. rpm -ivh wireshark-gnome-1.8.10-25.el6.x86_64.rpm

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The problem seems to be solved. To install tshark(CLI of wireshark) just do following:

```
sudo yum install wireshark
```

This will install tshark in `/usr/sbin/tshark`

To install wireshark with gui, do the following:

```
sudo yum install wireshark-gnome
```